# I need to update/Refresh my JSON Web Token

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, json-web-token

I need to update/refresh my JSON web token. I have a value of hasPaid that is created and stored inside of my JWT. It works successfully when I login. Because that is when the JWT is created. However, when I pay inside of the application; the JWT isn't updated to reflect that I have paid. And the JWT is reading this data from the database. So i need the JWT to update or refresh and reflect this change.

Here is where my JWT is created:

```
userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function() {
console.log("I'm creating a JSON WebToken");
console.log(this.hasPaid);
var expiry = new Date();
expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);
return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id,
    email: this.email,
    name: this.name,
    hasPaid : this.hasPaid,
    exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
}, "MY_SECRET"); // DO NOT KEEP YOUR SECRET IN THE CODE!
};
```

Here is my AJAX request where I make the payment. I need it update here:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8082/charge',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            stripeToken: response.id,
            currentUser: user
        },
        complete: function(response, state, e) {
            window.location.assign("video");
            return e.localStorage["token"]; // on success of ajax post update JWT
        }
    });
```

Comment: On your `/charge` route, generate a new token, send it back in the response and store it in local storage, when you front-end receives it. Profit!